# Output from `which` ignores redirects

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

Tried googling this, but with the command being called 'which', it's a little tricky!

My problem is this: I'm trying to redirect the output of the 'which' command so that it's silent, but it seems to ignore my redirections. Example:

```
#> which foo 2>&1 >/dev/null
/usr/bin/which: no foo in <my PATH>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: in my case, I'd like both success and failure messages to be suppressed, my script simply uses the exit code (and the failure message is messy).

Comment: NOTE: don't rely on the exit status of which! It *doesn't* necessarily tell you if the command exists or not! `which` is not portable in this way. In particular, you'll probably want these replacements: `case \`uname -s\` in
  SunOS) which() { ksh whence -p "$@"; } ;;
  HP-UX) which() { command -v "$@"; } ;;
esac`

Comment: Thanks! In this case the command is part of an install script which will only run on Linux, but I'll bear it in mind for the future!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put `2>&1` afterwards:

```
which foo >/dev/null 2>&1
```

or in Bash 4 and newer, simply:

```
which foo &>/dev/null
```

Comment: I'd guess this is because bash reads pipes/redirects right-to-left?

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between:

```
$ command 2>&1 > file
```

and

```
$ command > file 2>&1
```

What you want is the second one, i.e.

```
$ which foo >/dev/null 2>&1
```